# Wrong value being sent to converter JSF

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Final solution of the problem for getting the converter, equals and JSF code to work.

The Player is a Player bean with a few properties. The service access the Player and writes player info to the database (besides the point :)

```
<h:selectOneListbox size="1" value="#{player}" 
                converter="playerConverter" id="playerList">
            <f:selectItems value="#{servicePlayer.allPlayers}"
             var="n"
             itemValue="#{n}"
             itemLabel="#{n.combinedName}"
             itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
            </h:selectOneListbox>
```

In ServicePlayer

```
public List<Player> getAllPlayers() {

        if (factory == null) {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        }

        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Player t");

        List<Player> players = q.getResultList();

.... 

@FacesConverter(value = "playerConverter")
public class PlayerConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        long idValue;
        try {
            idValue = Long.parseLong(value);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ServicePlayer servicePlayer = context.getApplication()
                .evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{servicePlayer}",
                        ServicePlayer.class);
        Player player = servicePlayer.getPlayerByID(idValue);
        return player;

    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, 
                                  UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(((Player)value).getStringID()); 
        }
    }

}
```

In Player

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return (id != null && other != null && getClass() == other.getClass())
             ? id.equals(((Player) other).getId())
             : (other == this);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (id != null) 
             ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode()) 
             : super.hashCode();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to "switch" bean on selection in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629975/best-way-to-switch-bean-on-selection-in-jsf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this.

```
       <f:selectItems value="#{servicePlayer.allPlayers}"
             var="n"
             itemValue="#{n}"
             itemLabel="#{n.combinedName}"
             itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
        </h:selectOneListbox>
```

The *itemValue* should be the player object (n), **NOT** n.stringID, since the value of the `h:selectOneListbox` is a player object.

*getAsObject*

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, 
                          UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    long idValue;
    try {
        idValue = Long.parseLong(value);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }

    ServicePlayer servicePlayer = context.getApplication()
            .evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{servicePlayer}",
                    ServicePlayer.class);
    Player player = servicePlayer.getPlayerByID(idValue);
    return player;

}
```

*getAsString*

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, 
                              UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(((Player)value).getStringID()); 
                //or what ever the id is
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Please note that the Player MUST implement the equals and the hashcode methods.

**See Also:**

- [Validation error value is not valid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/9069660#9069660)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helps clearing some problems. However I am getting sourceId=j_idt12:playerList[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(j_idt12:playerList: Validation Error: Value is not valid), detail=(j_idt12:playerList: Validation Error: Value is not valid)] which means I can call the <h:commandButton value="Spara" action="#{serviceHCP.saveSerie(clubName, n, serieName, serie) }"></h:commandButton>

Comment: This means that the Player does NOT implement the equals and the hashcode. please consider implementing them.

Comment: More on equals ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/9069660#9069660

Answer (score 2):

in `getAsString` you are returning a `String` object, and in `getAsObject` you are trying to parse the value as `Long`:  `idValue = Long.parseLong(value);` which does not make any sense.

You should return the proper *id* in `getAsString` so you can get it in `getAsObject`.

*Updated*

E.g.
Your `getAsString` method should look like :

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return String.valueOf(((ServicePlayer) value).getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean that the getAsString should return a long? Since the ID is a long

Comment: Yes. You should return the long id value as String. e.g. String.valueOf(yourLongValue)

Comment: Getting a value error for the selectoneMenu now. Updated the question with the new getAs and error.

Comment: No, you didn't get my suggestion. Please have a look over my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a million for the comments and code. Can you please have a look at the final solution added to the question and see if I have missed anything?